# '$oid' is an illegal key in MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid

I've come across (and been stumped by) this error a couple times in Rails apps, when trying to save some data in a Hash field using MongoID:

`'$oid' is an illegal key in MongoDB`

I'm not sending any data with a key `$oid` into the hash, so I can't figure out what is causing it.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem is when I use the `id` field of another object in one of these hashes.  The id field of MongoID objects are not strings, they are `BSON::ObjectID`s, so if you try to stick them into a hash like this:

```rb
ObjectWithHash.update(hash_field: {name: a_name, id: other_object.id})
```

MongoId will try to convert `other_object.id` to Hash format, and come up with `{"$oid" => "......."}`, causing the error to show up.

To solve this, you can first convert it to a string and store that: `other_object.id.to_s`